# How to solve for $x$ when given function is $f(\ln(x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Someone asked me this question and I need a solution.
If $$f(\ln(x))=x^2$$ 
and $$f(x+1/x)=x-\frac{1}{x}$$ 
then find $f(x)$.

Comment: Using more words in your questions would do well for the quality standard. Also, writing mathematical expressions in within \$\$s. Also, properly tagging them. It's not a diophantine equation...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  for the first, let $y=\exp(x)$.  For the second, let $y=x+\frac 1x$ (assuming that is the argument of the function, and not $\frac {x+1}x$.  Please use parentheses when writing inline.  Are these truly diophantine equations, in which case the variables must be integers?  I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

hint 1: set $y:=\ln x$ for the first and $y:=x+\frac 1x$ for the second.

hint 2: for the second consider $y^2-4$